# Return value from nested function in another function if uses .then() or other method (JavaScript, Maps APIs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, nested-function, yandex-maps

I wrote AngularJS application which shows Google, Yandex and Gis maps for specific coordinates, obtained from JSON object. JSON may contains [0...n] objects.
And it is well works with Google Maps API, but not with Yandex/Gis Maps API.

Yandex Maps:

```
// DOESN'T WORK
$scope.yandexMaps = function (city) {
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init() {
        $scope.mapContainer = document.createElement('div');
        $scope.mapContainer.className = 'mapCon';
        $scope.yandexMap = new ymaps.Map($scope.mapContainer, {
            center: [city.lat, city.lng],
            zoom: 12
        });

        $scope.placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([city.lat, city.lng]);
        $scope.yandexMap.geoObjects.add($scope.placemark);
        return $scope.mapContainer; //I NEED TO GET IT !
    }
    //BUT I NEED TO GET IT THERE !
};
```

Gis Maps:

```
// DOESN'T WORK
$scope.gisMaps = function (city) {
    DG.then(init);
    function init() {
        $scope.mapContainer = document.createElement('div');
        $scope.mapContainer.className = 'mapCon';

        $scope.gisMap = DG.map($scope.mapContainer, {
            center: [city.lat, city.lng],
            zoom: 13
        });

        DG.marker([city.lat, city.lng]).addTo($scope.gisMap);
        return $scope.mapContainer; //I NEED TO GET IT !
    }
    //BUT I NEED TO GET IT THERE !
};
```

The problem is that `ymaps.ready(init);` and `DG.then(init);` call init() functions only after they will be checked for ready map state. And I can't return `$scope.mapContainer` in both cases because they are in nested functions.

I tried to create global variable above init() functions and assign to this `$scope.mapContainer`, but when I return this global value in parent below init() function it is not visible. It is visible only in nested function.

> YOU CAN SEE working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/oxpgkLhj/2/
> Please, open console to see errors
>
> If you are commenting this part at the end of code:

```
        //adding yandex map to common container
        $scope.yandexMap = $scope.yandexMap(value);
        $scope.yandexMap.id = "yandexMapContainer" + i;
        angular.element($scope.container).append($scope.yandexMap);
```

> and this:

```
        //adding gis map to common container
        $scope.gisMap = $scope.gisMaps(value);
        $scope.gisMap.id = "gisMapContainer" + i;
        angular.element($scope.container).append($scope.gisMap);
```

> you will see perfectly worked Google Maps. I want to see Yandex and Gis Maps exactly the same. Please help...

Comment: The yandexMaps function a has callback based API. The gisMaps function has a promise based API. Separate the problem into two questions.

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. A function can only return data that is immediately available or a *pending* promise that resolves to a value in the *future*.